# printf, print value to scientific notation

Tags: shell, awk, printf

I need to change two columns of a file to scientific notation.
The file looks like

```
test.txt
10177   1   A   AC  0.376827    0.0116338   0.0316735   0.713391    0.422784    0.936182
10352   1   T   TA  0.43176 0.00523364  0.0307872   0.865015    0.427932    0.680802
```

I have to change values in column 5 and 6 to scientific notation
I am aware of `printf "%1.3e", $5 test.txt` or `printf "%1.3e", $6 test.txt`.
However these commands add values from these columns in scientific notation at the beginning of `test.txt`.
How can i change values of columns 5 and 6 to scientific and keep them to be in column 5 and 6. Thank you for any suggestions.

Expect result would look like

```
test.txt
10177   1   A   AC  3.768e-01   1.163e-02   0.0316735   0.713391    0.422784    0.936182
10352   1   T   TA  4.318e-01   5.234e-03   0.0307872   0.865015    0.427932    0.680802
```

I am using the following code, which is obviously not correct :)

```
awk '{printf "%1.3e", $5}' test.txt > test1.txt
mv -f test1.txt test.txt
```

Comment: the expected result would be good

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thank you, i added it

Comment: Just write the output to a new file. Read the input file row by row, for every column other than 3/4 just copy as is to the new file. For columns 3/4 manipulate as needed and write the manipulated result to the new file.

Comment: @SHG thanks, but im looking for a way to do it without creating  a new file

Comment: @Updating the file in place is very difficult and generally not worth it.  In particular, if you try to update it in-llace, you will have to ensure that the scientific notation representation always has exactly as many characters as the existing numbers.  (The issue is that there's no good way to insert or delete characters in an existing file.)

Comment: From the snippets, this doesn't look like [tag:c]. Is this about some other (probably scripting) language? maybe even the *command* `printf`  available on some systems?

Comment: You will be hard put to do that without creating a new file: in line 2 you will have to realign every numeric field, even those that do not change format, and the new line is longer than the original.

Comment: @ThePooh what about writing it to a new file, and then override the old one with it? ;) You end up with the same result.

Comment: @SHG i have tried and the result was printed to first column, so order of columns was changed

Comment: @ThePooh So it means you didn't do it right, that's all. Maybe publish your code and it will help us to help you?

Comment: @SHG thank you,  i added it to the question

Comment: @ SHG not me who added c there, someone edited my question

Comment: @ThePooh got you now. Added an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Agreed. Just meant bash scripting in general. I used `awk` myself.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for clarifying. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do the trick:

```
awk '{printf "%d %d %s %s %1.3e %1.3e %f %f %f %f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}' test.txt > test1.txt
mv -f test1.txt test.txt
```

Change the spaces/tabs between the columns as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v OFS='   ' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf (i~/^[56]$/?"%1.3e":"%s")"%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
10177   1   A   AC   3.768e-01   1.163e-02   0.0316735   0.713391   0.422784   0.936182
10352   1   T   TA   4.318e-01   5.234e-03   0.0307872   0.865015   0.427932   0.680802
```

Add `-i inplace` with GNU awk to avoid explicitly creating the tmp file if that matter to you:

```
$ cat file
10177   1   A   AC  0.376827    0.0116338   0.0316735   0.713391    0.422784    0.936182
10352   1   T   TA  0.43176 0.00523364  0.0307872   0.865015    0.427932    0.680802
$
$ awk -i inplace -v OFS='   ' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf (i~/^[56]$/?"%1.3e":"%s")"%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
$
$ cat file
10177   1   A   AC   3.768e-01   1.163e-02   0.0316735   0.713391   0.422784   0.936182
10352   1   T   TA   4.318e-01   5.234e-03   0.0307872   0.865015   0.427932   0.680802
```

See the man page for details.